# Right now i've been having an issue

Tags: python, conda

So, pip is acting Wierd, but that is besides the point.
I have conda. Simple, right? Nope.
Every time i get the HTTP 000 error, y'know the one.
but this one's different.
there's no Max Retries at the bottom, as shown here:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

If you're asking, the only thing I did was update Conda

Comment: Have you tried accessing `https://www.anaconda.com`? If so, what does it result in?

Comment: it works, i tried it before.